# Some ideals in $k[[x,y]]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

I have an ideal in $k[[x,y]]$, and I know that it contains $x$ but isn't $\langle x \rangle$ (here $k$ is a field, maybe not alg closed).  This means that my ideal must be of the form $\langle x ,y^n \rangle$ for some $n$.

This is not hard to prove, but a proof isn't what I'm looking for.  What I want is the suitable commutative algebra lingo: how do I explain this fact in as few words as possible?  What more general principle is at work?

Comment: The ideals of $k\left[\left[x,y\right]\right]$ containing $x$ are in 1-to-1 correspondence with ideals of $k\left[\left[x,y\right]\right] / \left(x\right)$. But $k\left[\left[x,y\right]\right] / \left(x\right) \cong k\left[\left[y\right]\right]$ (this follows from $k\left[\left[x,y\right]\right] = \left(k\left[\left[y\right]\right]\right)\left[\left[x\right]\right]$), so we are looking for the ideals of $k\left[\left[y\right]\right]$. And that should be well-known.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general principles are:
(1) [the correspondence theorem for ideals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/39370/ideal-correspondence), and
(2) the isomorphism $R[[X]]/(X)\simeq R$ for any commutative ring $R$.